# Char arithmetic in Haskell

Tags: haskell, char

In many languages you can write `'A' + i` for some integer i to get a letter of the alphabet. How can I do this in Haskell? (And also the reverse operation like `let ch = 'B' in (ch - 'A')) == 1`)

```
Prelude> 'A' + 1
    No instance for (Num Char) arising from a use of `+'
```

Comment: `ord` and `chr` from [`Data.Char`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/Data-Char.html#g:6) convert between Int and Char.

Comment: By the way, `Char` is an instance of [`Enum`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/Prelude.html#t:Enum).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can convert between `Int` and `Char` with functions from `Data.Char`. However this isn't as implicit as you are asking for.

If you really want this, you can in theory make a `Num` instance, for example as follows:

```
import Data.Char (chr, ord)

instance Num Char where
    c1 + c2 = chr (ord c1 + ord c2)
    c1 - c2 = chr (ord c1 - ord c2)
    fromInteger = chr . fromInteger
```

And then you get

```
> 'A' + 1
'B'

> 'B' - 'A' == 1
True
```

But it's rather a hack because a `Char` isn't really a number.

In particular notice what happens if you actually inspect the value of `'B' - 'A'`:

```
> 'B' - 'A'
'\SOH'
```

i.e. you get the character `1` rather than actually seeing it as an `Int`. The equality check above works because `1` is converted to a `Char`, but you don't get an implicit conversion in reverse.

I've also omitted some of the other operations from `Num` so you'll get compiler warnings and some operations won't work. You can add them along the same lines, but they make even less sense.

Comment: No need to implement other Num Class functions such as `signum` ?

Comment: I mentioned that in my last paragraph (ninja-edited in, so you may not have seen it originally) - they would be needed for some things in theory, but doing that on `Char` is even more weird so I omitted them for the purposes of the explanation.

Comment: I ended up using `chr` and `ord`, but I may as well accept the only answer given.